# HTTP Error 500 when i access the website

Tags: joomla, sles

I am hosting website www.cdnl.info and when I try to access it and I get the HTTP Error 500. What could be the problem and how can I solve it?
It happened after I tried to make a copy of the website folder. The server is environment is SLES 10.3

Comment: Please do some research, this question has been asked countless times

Comment: almost all the solutions I get are based on windows and IIS

Comment: Have you read the logfile?

Comment: I have and this is the error i get : [Tue Dec 02 11:45:01 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  require(/srv/www/htdocs/CDNL/wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/htdocs/CDNL/index.php on line 17. I was not the one who set up the site two years ago and i checked the file and it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the configuration.php and set "Error Reporting" to maximum. Try visiting the website. If you don't see the error then you rename your .htaccess file to htaccess.txt and visit the website again. At this point you should probably see the error.

If not, then check your server error logs which will give you an insight on why this is happening.

Worse comes to worst, what we usually do is initiating a debug on the index.php file.